# Check validity of element in an array of objects and then retrieve that object and its index?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a simple array of objects:

```
var cars: [Car] = [Car(ID: "010", name: "car1"), Car(ID: "230", name: "car2"), Car(ID: "350", name: "car3")]
```

The user will use a `UITextfield` to enter an ID.

I will then have to check the array to see if there is an object that has this exact ID, if such an object exists I need to retrieve the object and the index where it is located.

In addition I need to update a flag variable to know whether the user entered a correct or incorrect number. As I will use this to change other aspects of the view controller (such as lay-out).

I currently have this function that receives the ID as parameter and then returns a tuple for another function. The carObject and indexOfCar are global variables that have to be updated:

```
    func checkIdMatch(IdInput: String) -> (Bool, Car?) {
        var returnObject: Car?
        var tuple = (false, returnObject)

        for (index, car) in cars.enumerated() {
            if car.carId == IdInput {
                returnObject = car
                tuple = (true, car)

                carObject = car
                indexOfCar = index
                flag = 2 //correct ID
            } else {
                flag = 1 //wrong ID
            }
        }
        self.tableView?.reloadData()
        return tuple
    }
```

I tried to use a `where` statement after the for()-statement, but then I couldn't update the flags correctly. What am I doing wrong?
Any help is immensely appreciated!

Comment: Why not simply return a optional `Car`? If it's `nil` the object is not in the array, otherwise the `Car` object is returned. The `Bool` and the extra `flag` variable are actually redundant. And the loop is very expensive, you should leave it when the item is found.

Comment: Why don't you use `filter`  to retrieve your car by `Id` instead using the index ? 
Something like `let yourCar = cars.filter( {  $0.ID == "YOURID"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on here, I'm going to try to address everything, one at a time:

1. In your code, you never break your loop early when you find a match.

   - There are obvious performance implications
   - Has the (probably undesired) side effect that `flag` keeps getting set over and over again. Thus, `flag` will only be `2` if the correct ID is found last in the array (so that there's no next element for which it'll be set back to `1`).
2. Your flag is a raw integer. It should probably be an enumeration.
3. Your `cars` array has an unnecessary type annotation `: [Car]` can (and should) be left to the compiler to infer.
4. Your `(Bool, Car?)` tuple is superfluous. It's a clever idea in feneral: pairing a data value with a data value (such as a `Car` instance, in this case) with a `Bool` value that represents whether or not the data value is non-null. Apple liked this design so much, in fact, that this is exactly how `Optional` works! You just need to return `Car?`, which can either be a valid instance, or `nil`.
5. Your `returnObject` variable is never used, and ironically, never returned.
6. Your function called `checkIdMatch(IdInput:)` not only checks if an ID matches, but also removes it from the array, changes global state, and refreshes your table view. This doesn't sound like "checking" to me!
7. Your function name, and its parameter use `Id`, whereas your `Car` uses `ID`. Inconsistent.
8. Your function's parameter doesn't need the `Input` suffix. We know that parameters are inputs.
9. `carObject` and `indexOfCar` probably shouldn't be globals, but I don't have enough context to be able to tell. In any case, wouldn't `indexOfCar` always be inaccurate? You're storing the index where the `Car` is, but then you immediately remove the car, so the index is now wrong.
10. You use copious amounts of so called "side effects". This is when a function has an effect apart from just processing its parameters into some return value. This is unavoidable in many cases, but having lots of side effects make code really hard to work with, hard to maintain, and hard to extend. Wherever possible, try to minimize side effects and reliance on global state. Ideally, you should try to write "pure" functions. Those that have no effect beyond returning a result. They're much, much easier to work with.

Here's my first attempt:

```
struct Car {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}

enum Flag: Int { //TODO: Name me!
    case original
    case noMatch
    case match
}

var flag = Flag.noMatch;

var cars = [Car(id: "010", name: "car1"), Car(id: "230", name: "car2"), Car(id: "350", name: "car3")]

func removeCar(ID: String) -> Car? {
    guard let index = cars.index(where: {$0.id == id}) else {
        flag = .noMatch //TODO: side effects make kittens cry
        return nil
    }

    flag = .match //TODO: side effects make kittens cry
    return cars.remove(at: index)
}

print("Before:\r\n\(cars)\r\n\r\n")
print("Removed:\r\n\(removeCar(id: "350"))\r\n\r\n")
print("After:\r\n\(cars)\r\n\r\n")
```

[You can try it online, here.](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/5811f13c93f80b1c6b804e84)

Comment: Nice answer – although you forgot to follow your own advice and remove the explicit type annotation on `cars` ;) The only thing that I would add is that it's naming convention for everything except type names to be `lowerCamelCase` (for example, the `ID` parameter name for `removeCar` and the property on `Car` should be `id`). Also depending on how the `flag` is used, it may be better suited as a simple `Bool` (although only if OP can think of a more descriptive name for it than `flag` – `idWasMatched` maybe).

Comment: Although in any case, as you rightly say, the use of `flag` looks suspiciously like an abuse of state, and possibly redundant – the caller can tell what the value of `flag` should be by whether the result is `nil` or not.

Comment: @Hamish, and Alex, Thank you for all the help! The combination of the 'guard let' statement with the index(where: ) method was exactly the thing I needed :) . With these tips I also managed to simplify my code and remove some of the superfluous things (like the tuple) as well. I think I still need the flag (as enum) like it is now. Because it is later used in the cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection methods with 3 states (original, match, noMatch), as I need multiple prototypecells in an UITableView to change height (when it reloads) depending on what the flag is...

Comment: @Aovib I've updated the enumeration in my answer to suite your need. Enumerations can have "raw values". Essentially, such an enumeration is a pretty way of defining and working with `Int` constants. Just by specifying that the raw value type is `Int`, the cases automatically get the values `0, 1, 2, ...` assigned. If you wish to specify different numbers, you can either reorder your cases, or use the equals sign to explicitly set values.

Comment: @Aovib such a raw value can be accessed by calling `flag.rawValue`. An enum can be set from a raw value, too, like `flat = Flag(rawValue: 1)`.  Check out [the language guide's section on enumerations with raw values](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID149).